# How to create dynamic Linq Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Where can I learn about creating a 'dynamic' linq expression?
I need to turn this into something dynamic because the currentUser is null when the code is excecuted in the OnModelCreating of Entity Framework. I am trying to create a global query filter.

```
User currentUser = currentUserService.GetUser();
IPermissionService permissionService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPermissionService>();

var allowedToSee = Entities.Where(e => permissionService.HasPermission(e, currentUser).View);
modelBuilder.Entity<Audit>().HasQueryFilter(x => allowedToSee.Contains(x.EntityType));
```

This is the audit class:

```
public class Audit
    {
        // Information about changes

        public virtual Entity EntityType { get; set; }
    }
```

Example of other dynamic linq expression:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        { 
            //If the actual entity is an auditable type. 
            if(typeof(Auditable).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                //This adds (In a reflection type way), a Global Query Filter
                //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters
                //That always excludes deleted items. You can opt out by using dbSet.IgnoreQueryFilters()
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
                var deletedCheck = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "DateDeleted"), Expression.Constant(null)), parameter);
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(deletedCheck);
            }
        }
        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show `Audit` class definition?

Comment: Can you inject `permissionService` into `DbContext` constructor?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following `DbContext` and `AllowedToSee` property is properly implemented, `ApplyAuditFilters` should apply query filter to all `Audit` descendants.

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ApplyAuditFilters(modelBuilder);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    // implement this property
    public IEnumerable<Entity> AllowedToSee => throw new NotImplementedException();

    private void ApplyAuditFilters(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var types = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .Where(et => typeof(Audit).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType));

        var thisExpression = Expression.Constant(this);

        // this.AllowedToSee
        var allowedToSeeExpr = Expression.Property(thisExpression, nameof(AllowedToSee));

        foreach (var et in types)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(et.ClrType, "e");

            // e.EntityType
            var filterPropertyExpr = Expression.Property(param, nameof(Audit.EntityType));

            // this.AllowedToSee.Contains(e.EntityType)
            var filterBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains), new[] { typeof(Entity) },
                allowedToSeeExpr, filterPropertyExpr);

            // e => this.AllowedToSee.Contains(e.EntityType)
            var queryFilter = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, param);

            modelBuilder.Entity(et.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(queryFilter);
        }
    }

    ... // other members
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it will work! But I get the error `System.ArgumentException: 'Instance property 'AllowedToSee' is not defined for type 'Namespace.Context' Arg_ParamName_Name'` when `ApplyAuditFilters()` is called

Comment: This is my current code: https://pastebin.com/4Q2HmPP0

Comment: `AllowedToSee` should be read-only property, but you have created function.

Comment: I got it working using `var methodInfo = 
typeof(ChainWiseContext).GetMethod(nameof(AllowedToSee));` `var allowedToSeeExpr = Expression.Call(thisExpression, methodInfo);` but now I got the error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Entity>().Where(e => _permissionService_0.HasPermission(entity: e, user: _currentUser_1).View)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'` I need to use it as a method

Comment: You have to go with property, or do not use EF Core.

Comment: Also exception shows, that you have used not even method,  but something else.

Answer (score -1):

If you need 'dynamic' linq, I recommend using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).

And here is the [documentation for it](https://dynamic-linq.net/overview).

However, I'm not sure that this would be the best solution in your case. But if you want to dynamically generate linq expressions, then this is a good and easy way to do it.